# Issue while writing data in Hive using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am working in Pyspark where i am doing some operation in a dataframe and then appending it to an existing hive table. The solution works perfect in development environment but in testing i am getting `org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable`

I made sure that the table schema is same in both the environment but still no luck. I tried casting the schema in PySpark but still the code fails to run in testing enviornment.
Below is my code snippet where i am casting the columns in Pyspark. Because of company policy i can not share more code and also need to change the name of the columns.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, LongType, DoubleType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
col_map = {'id':StringType(),
           'booking_time':StringType(),
           'perd':LongType(),
           'sequence':LongType(),
           'm':StringType(),
           'a':DoubleType(),
           'b':DoubleType(),
           'c':DoubleType(),
           'd':DoubleType(),
           'e':DoubleType(),
           'f':DoubleType(),
           'g': DoubleType(),
           'h':DoubleType(),
           'record_time':StringType()}

change_results= change_results.select([F.col(c).cast(col_map[c]).alias(c) for c in change_results.columns])
```

Below is the statement i am using for writing the data into the hive table.

```
st_cols = spark.sql(f"""select * from {args.change_table}""").columns
logger.info("Writing")
change_results.select(st_cols).write.mode('append').insertInto(args.change_table)
```

Below is the table schema. Column names is removed since its confidential data.
[image: Hive table schema]
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried : `write.saveAsTable(args.change_table, mode="append")` ?

Comment: @Steven i didnt `change_results.select(st_cols).write.mode('append').insertInto(args.change_table)` seems to be the one followed across the team. What is the difference bw these two approaches

Comment: the schema in your screenshot is in dev or prod? are you sure they're both the same?

Comment: @pltc same schema is present in dev and test environment.